# Completing the proof of a theorem

Tags: measure-theory

My question is about the proof of the Theorem 1.3 which is on the page 9 of the book ["Topics in Real Analysis"](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-ra/index.html), which is available electronically through the previous link.

I want to demonstrate that theorem in the case $\mu (X)=\infty$. In that book there's the following tip:

> To extend our result to the general case observe that the finite case implies $\mu (A\cap X_j)=\tilde \mu (A\cap X_j)$ (**just restrict** $\mu,\tilde\mu$ to $X_j$). Hence
>
> $$\mu (A)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu (A\cap X_j)=\lim_{j\to \infty}\tilde \mu(A\cap X_j)=\tilde \mu (A)$$

Below is my attempt to use that tip to prove that theorem in the case $\mu (X)=\infty$.

Let $j\in\mathbb{N}$ be any element and define $S_j:=\big\{E\cap X_j:E\in S\big\}$. It's trivial to verify that $S_j$ is a $\pi$[-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) (because $S$ is by hypothesis a $\pi$-system). Besides, since $X_j\in S$, then $S_j\subseteq S$ which implies that $\Sigma (S_j)\subseteq\Sigma (S)=\Sigma $ in which $\Sigma (S_j)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S_j$.

Let $\mu _{S_j}$ and $\tilde \mu _{S_j}$, respectively, be the restrictions of $\mu$ and $\tilde \mu$ to $\Sigma(S_j)$. It's easy to see that $(X_j,\Sigma (S_j),\mu_{S_j})$ is a measure space.

The elements of $\{X_j\cap X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ belongs to $S_j$ and satisfy $(X_j\cap X_n)\nearrow X_j$ and $\mu_{X_j}(X_j\cap X_n)<\infty $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Because of the above considerations and $\mu_{S_j}(X_j)<\infty$, we can use the first part of the proof of the Theorem 1.3 which is in the book mentioned above to prove that $\mu_{S_j}(E)=\tilde \mu_{S_j}(E)\,\,\color{red}{(1)}$ for all $E\in \Sigma (S_j)$.

Let $A\in\Sigma $ be any element.

If there's a $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A\cap X_j\in \Sigma (S_j)$, then I can use $(1)$ and that tip above to prove that $\mu (A)=\tilde \mu (A)$. However, if $A\cap X_j\,\,{\color{red}{\notin}} \,\,\Sigma (S_j)$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$, then I can't use $(1)$ and, therefore, that tip is useless.

Please help me to finish the proof. At least indicate some reference that contains the proof of that theorem.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the $S_j$ you've defined are the best they can be, in the sense that the condition you speak of as a problem, cannot happen! Basically , your work so far is correct, and what I'm going to show is that for every $A \in \Sigma$, we have $A \cap X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$ for every $j$.

---

Why can't that condition happen? Well, $S$ generates $\Sigma$. $S_j$ is just every element of $S$ intersected with $X_j$.  Now because any intersections, unions etc. behave nicely with respect to just an intersection with some $X_j$, the sigma-algebra generated by $S_j$ creates every possible intersection of an element of $\Sigma$ , and $X_j$. In one line : $S$ approximates $\Sigma$, and intersecting with an $X_j$ (or any set in $\Sigma$) should still retain the approximation.

---

The precise statement is this :

> $$
> \Sigma = \{F \in \Sigma : F \cap X_j \in \Sigma(S_j) \ \ \forall j = 1,2,...\}
> $$

That is, there's no set $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \cap X_j \notin \Sigma(S_j)$ for *any single* (forget about all) $j$. Note that $\Sigma(S_j)$ is a sigma-algebra of subsets of $X_j$ by construction (you are using this because the probability space is set up that way). Therefore $X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$.

To prove this, note that $S$ is a subset of the RHS by definition of $S_j$. So we only need to prove that the RHS is a sigma-algebra. Let's call the RHS as $T$.

- Note that $\emptyset \cap X_j = \emptyset \in \Sigma(S_j)$ for all $j$ and $X \cap X_j = X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$. So $0,X \in T$.
- Let $F \in T$. We know that $F \cap X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$ for all $j$. Now, remember that $\Sigma(S_j)$ are sigma-algebras of $X_j$, so when I take a complement, $(F \cap X_j)^c = F^c \cap X_j$ for each $j$, because I am taking the complement corresponding to each $X_j$. Therefore, $F^c \cap X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$ for all $j$ and thus $F^c \in T$.
- Let $F_i \in T$ be countably many sets. Then , note that :
  $$
  \left(\cup_{i=1}^\infty F_i\right) \cap X_j = \cup_{i=1}^\infty(F_i \cap X_j)
  $$
  now if I fix a $j$, then $F_i \cap X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$ for all $i$, so from the above we get $(\cup_{i=1}^\infty F_i) \cap X_j \in S_j$ for all $j$ so $\cup_{i=1}^\infty F_i \in T$.

Therefore, $T$ is a sigma-algebra, so $T$ contains $\Sigma(S) = \Sigma$. So $T = \Sigma$.

---

Now, let $A \in \Sigma$. Then $A \in T$. So $A \cap X_j \in \Sigma(S_j)$ for all $j$. From the result for $\Sigma(S_j)$, we know that $\mu(A \cap X_j) = \tilde{\mu}(A \cap X_j)$ for every $j$. Now $A \cap X_j \uparrow A$, you can conclude.

I actually ran into a very similar issue when I dealt with a similar problem. It turns out that this has to do with a far more general statement concerning pull-backs of sigma-algebras.

I state that as follows :

> Let $f : (S,\mathcal S) \to (F , \mathcal F)$ be measurable. Let $\mathcal E \subset \mathcal F$. Then, we have :
> $$
> f^{-1}(\Sigma(E)) = \Sigma(f^{-1}(E))
> $$

That is, pulling back every set in $\Sigma(E)$ to give a sigma-algebra is equivalent to pulling back every set of $E$ and generating a sigma-algebra out of that. We can use this result to prove the above equality of sigma-algebras very easily, using the inclusion map from $X_j \to X$ for each $j$. Use this to prove that $\Sigma(S_j) = \{A \cap X_j : A \in \Sigma\}$ for each $j$, which of course leads to the theorem I wrote down.

Being comfortable with simple lemmas and theorems around sigma-algebras is very important if you want to far into probability, especially when conditioning, martingales etc. come into play.